# Can't see undelete votes for deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, votes, user-page

See discussion in chat [starting here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9661865#9661865).

I was looking for a list of the posts I'd voted to undelete, [replace my username with yours to see your list - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/603/menachem?tab=votes&sort=undelete ], but the list was incomplete.

Looks like the list hides posts that are presently deleted, even though I have enough reputation to see the actual post itself.

If I can vote to undelete the post, doesn't that mean that I have enough reputation to see the deleted post? Therefore, shouldn't the list of "votes for undeletion" include posts that are presently deleted?

Comment: I'm going to re-tag this as a feature request, while wonky, the current behavior is what's expected.

Comment: @TimPost: Does that mean that at present there is no way to view deleted posts I voted to undelete?

Comment: @Menachem, for ones that are still awaiting enough votes, I guess you could dig them out of the delete-votes page under the 10k tools?  Big hassle as there's no way to know [which are yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182275/162102), though. :-(

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140328/dont-hide-undeletion-votes-cast-on-deleted-posts

Answer (score 5):

Starting in the next build, 10k+ users will be able to see all of their votes from the appropriate sub-tabs of their profiles.

[From the Dave Haney](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235210/166017), the dev who implemented this:

> I've modified the code so that 10K users can see votes on (un)deleted posts under the appropriate tabs (deletion, undelete) of the votes section of their profile. This will be live in the next prod build (> rev `2014.7.3.2354`). Please let me know if you have any questions!